# sdcc on Raspberry PI

Tags: software-development

Has anyone managed to install sdcc (http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) on a Raspberry?
The package repository has `sddc-doc` and `sdcc-libraries` but the main package `sdcc` seems missing!

Their site says that sdcc can be compiled for Raspberry but I'd like to check if anyone has done it before.

Comment: Doesn't look like it would pose any problems. Try compiling from source and post the results.

Comment: Just completed the compilation. Roughly 6 hours on my Raspberry :)

Comment: But something must be wrong ... I got a syntax error on a line like this. `sfr at 0x80 p0;`

Comment: Have you tried figuring out why the error occurs? It'd be nice if you could answer your own question, in case someone ask's the same question.

Comment: Does that line work on sdcc on another architecture? (Is it RPi specific?)

Answer (score 2):

I compiled sdcc successfull about one week ago, when you start ./configure in sdcc direcotry you will see which file is missing, you have to install some lib and dev packages.
Packages i installed before compilation: gputils bison flex libboost-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-thread-dev

Answer (score 0):

I typed in "sudo apt install sdcc" and it just all worked fine on an Raspberry Pi 4.